# Is possible to know the streaming channel subscriptions of an user?

Tags: streaming-api

I subscribe an user to a streaming channel when a button in a component is pressed. The problem is that the user can close and reopen the page of the component and push the button again, so in this case, the same user would be subscribed twice to the same streaming channel.

Exists any way of checking the active subscriptions of an users? If so, I could check if the user already has an active subscription and prevent it to subcript twice.

Thank you.